# How does this AngularJS Filter work? Give me some description

Tags: angularjs

I used AngularJS Filter to search some data.
First, set param to search.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="setParam">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="ptName">Name</option>
    <option value="ptCeo">CEO</option>
    <option value="ptAddr">Address</option>
    <option value="ptTel">Tel</option>
</select>
```

And then, input search text.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="ptParam[setParam]">
```

In this code, `ng-model="ptParam[setParam]"` is gonna be filter and used like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="row in filterData = (partners | filter: setParam ? ptParam : '')">
```

It works well, but I wanna know how does `ng-model="ptParam[setParam]"` work?
Can I get some description?

Comment: May I get how is `partners` modelled?

Comment: `partners` is list of `partner`, and `partner` has ptName, ptCeo, ptAddr, ... etc.

Comment: what is ptParam?

Comment: Does the description from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) sufficiently explain it? Zoom in to the section on _expression_ where an `Object` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ptParam[setParam] is the way to access to the ptParam’s property named like the actual setParam value. It’s called “bracket notation”. 
For example:

`person['firstname'] = 'Mario';`

But in you case you invocked with a variable, with the selected value.

Comment: well.. I didn't know it is possible to access Object's property like that. It looks weird.So is it same `ptParam.setParam`, right?

Comment: You can check this basic example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand all of it.

Comment: You can’t use the traditional dot notation because your ptParam object doesn’t have a property called “setParam”

Comment: Yes. You mean `ptParam.setParam` is just `ptParam['setParam']`, right? To access Object's property using variable, I should use "bracket notation".

Comment: The result of doing ptParam.setParam will be undefined, cause your object doesn’t have a property named like that. If you use the bracket notation and setParam = “ptName” for example, doing ptParam[setParam] is like ptParam.ptName (the variables names are not the best choice :/ )